# How would I make an app that changes the notification window?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-theme, android-notification-bar

I want to make an app that can control how the notification window looks (i.e. the overlay the shows all your notifications when you swipe down from the top status bar). Is this possible? What APIs would I need to be able to do this (and know what notifications are current, etc)?

Comment: "Is this possible?" -- only by downloading the Android source code, revising it with your changes, and turning the results into a ROM mod.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case? If so, that's a major limitation. What if the phone was rooted?

Comment: "Are you sure this is the case?" -- 99%. "What if the phone was rooted?" -- you then have a rooted phone that has the notification bar from the OS/ROM mod that is installed upon it.